# Drupal 7: How to attach node create form to user register form

Tags: drupal-7

On user register form I want to attach all fields of a content type and then on submit to create a new node of that content type.

For example every time user registers he will need to fill-in the information about the COMPANY (company is a content type with a lot of fields) and that will further create the new node with that company info associated with the USER-ID.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can make an use of [PROFILE 2 module](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2). This module avails the linking of Entity Type with User Profile. You can create the Profile 2 type with the required CCK fields and link that with the USER PROFILE.

Comment: I already use profile 2 module to attach profile type form to user register form but I need to attach node create form to user register form and then on submit to create a new node by that content type

Comment: Please explain more about what kind of NODE TYPE you need to attach to user profile.

Comment: I created for example a custom content type: company with a lot of fields and I want to attach company fields to user register form.

Comment: I just want to understand it even better ---> is it the case that every time user registers he will need to fill-in the information about the COMPANY and that will further create the new node with that company info associated with the USER-ID.

Comment: Please edit the post and mention all these details in the question as well :)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it with the user profile, but I guess you could achieve what you want with [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) and [References Dialog](https://www.drupal.org/project/references_dialog). References dialog adds links to the node edit form, with which the user can add, edit or search for references. For example: I have two content types "Shop" and "Shop Contact". When an editor adds a "shop"-node, the node edit form contains a dialog with which the editor can seach existing "shop-contact"-nodes or add a new one (in a modal window), without leaving the node edit form of the "shop"-node. With Profile2, add a reference to your company content type via references dialog and make it a mandatory field.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a small module for this purpose.
first create a block in your `mymodule.module` file.

```
function mymodule_block_info() {
    $blocks = array();
    $blocks['Node_add_form'] = array(
    'info' => t('Node add form'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE, // this will exclude the block from Drupal cache
  );

  return $blocks;
}
```

Then you have to show block contents,

```
function mymodule_block_view($delta = '') {
    if (!function_exists('node_add')) { 
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    $form = node_add('Your_NODE_TYPE');  }
    $output = drupal_render($form);
    $block = array();
    switch ($delta) {
        case 'qs_forum_topic_add':

    if (!user_is_logged_in()){ // Change this condition according to your's
    $block['title'] = t('If any title');
    $block['content'] = $output; }
}
```

This has created a node add form and created a block in `/admin/structure/blocks` place this block on `/user/register` with any kind of means(context, pane, code)etc as convenient to you.

Comment: This logic with block will create 2 submit buttons which (one for node add form and one for the user register form) which is not I need.

Comment: You can create another custom callback function    `$form['actions']['submit'][] = 'your_custom_callback';`  on form submit for user registration  form.